# How to send an invoice to different email address in magento 2

Tags: email, customer-account, invoice, magento2.3.1, customer-registration

How can I send an invoice email to a different email address?

1. I have created a customer attribute which is used to save email address while the user creates their account.
2. Once the customer is created and they place an order, the invoice should be sent the different email address (customer attribute) instead of using the customer email.

Answer (score 1):

I put together an extension which cc's email to another address as well as the purchaser. You could adapt it slightly so that this is the cc is the only email that is used.

Here it is

https://github.com/DominicWatts/EmailCC